# c# class data structure, dependencies and pointer problems

Tags: c#, arrays, class, constructor, customization

EDIT:

Okay let me try to explain:

I want to manage a data array of points from an external source, with
a dataclass, where I store this array like this:

```
public Data(int [,] point)

{
    SomeBlockingCollection.Add(point);
}
```

No problem here. 
Now lets assume the point has three integer values: x,y,temp, so it would look like this if you look into the array:

```
point[0,0] = 2; //This is P1
point[0,1] = 8; 
point[0,2] = 10;

point[1,0] = 30; //This is P2
point[1,1] = 5;
point[1,2] = 20;
```

And so on...

Now what I also want to store in my Data object is a reference to these points.
From my external source there will be another array, which should stores pointers to my array of points.

So that I have a class which looks like that:

```
public Data(int [,] point, int[][] pointers)

{
    SomeBlockingCollection.Add(point);
}
```

If you would look into the pointers array it would look like that(sorry i do not know how to correctly do the syntax):

```
pointers[0] = [P1,P2,Pn];
pointers[1] = [P2,Pn,P1};
```

So basically I want to store to things in my data object from outside:

1. An Array of a Custom Point Object with three values
2. An Array of surfaces, where each surface consists of three pointers(which represent points in my first array) to my Custom Point Object Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right, then you really wondering if objects in the array will be the same objects. If you have classes and only use references, then they will be, e.g.

```
var array1 = new Point[] { new Point(...), new Point(...), new Point(...) };
var array2 = new Point[2];
array2[0] = array1[2];
```

In this case there will be still 3 points in memory with one of them referenced twice.

If I follow your requirements, then you will:

1. Read all your points into big array (if you don't know the initial size, you can read them in a List as well.
2. Create "small" arrays that will have reference to the points that you already have
3. Initialize you data structures with small arrays

e.g.

```
public class MyData
{
   Point[] m_Points;
   public MyData(Point[] points)
   {
       m_Points = points;
   }
}
```

Comment: But how do I do this in a constructor or a data class? The data i get from an external source certainly won't be a Point class, My problem is I need to create a Point class somehow in c# and then give it to the constructor so that i can say "data n1= new data(Points[],string,int,...)"

Comment: I have updated my answer, but I am not 100% sure I understand what you want to achieve...

Comment: i have updated my post, i hope it is more understandable now? thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a two dimensional array for your points? It's much more clear to create array of Point like in my example, where Point will have x, y, z. It should not be a big difference from performance point of view (unless you have some critical operation), but will be much easier to operate, and you will be able to pass a reference to any given point further.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly each time you want to assign a new point to your NewArray you make a new instance of Point Class. Don't do this!

instead do it like this :

```
NewArray[m] = Points[n]
```